# How to get line number during SAX parsing with libxml in ruby?

Tags: ruby, saxparser, libxml-ruby

I'm trying to count line numbers during SAX parsing for detecting errors in the XML document with some rules. 
Tags like this `<CITY>London</CITY>` respond on callbacks `on_start_element_ns` and `on_end_element_ns` and tags like this

```
<BUYER>
  <BUYER_ID>00001</BUYER_ID>
  <BUYER_NAME>Buyer_1</BUYER_NAME>
</BUYER>
```

respond only for `on_start_element_ns` callback. I'm using SAX parser because I have very big files. Any ideas how to find correct line number for each tag?

**UPDATE**

I've used **Ox** and it has solved my problem. Ox SAX parser has line numbers contrary to libxml and nokogiri.

Comment: Which SAX parser are you using?

Comment: This one [libxml-ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/libxml-ruby)